# Using JavaScript function on div click on a div that has been fetched using get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done some searching and can't find an answer to this so I guess I'll ask my first question on here.

Basically, on the click of a div, I am fetching some html using get and appending to the bottom of a div. The fetched html includes the same div that was originally clicked on. I need that to be clickable to run the same function as that original div. This is hard to explain and is made more complicated by the use of JScrollPane

So this is the relevant JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
$(document).on('click', 'div#append-tweets', function () {

    //The url is altered to collect the next page of tweets in my example, but this will do
    var currentURL = document.URL;


    currentURL = currentURL + " #content-area > *";

    //gets data from the url
    $.get(currentURL, function (data) {

        //finds the tweets on the page and returns them as HTML
        html = $(data).find('#content-area').html();
        //appends the html to the div - uses api as this is the JScrollPane
        api.getContentPane().append(html);

    }, 'html');

    //reload the scrollbar
    api.reinitialise();

    //makes div button disappear after it is clicked
    document.getElementById('append-tweets').style.display = "none";

});
});
```

And this is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="content-area">
//other stuff

    <div id="append-tweets">Load More Tweets</div>

</div>
```

At the moment, the function runs on the first click, and it all works fine. The button div disappears (which is good), the new content is loaded, including the new button div but that one isn't clickable, even though it has the same ID. Thanks in advance for any help, I am quite new to JS and JQuery.

Comment: "even though it has the same ID". maybe that's your problem then? give the new items the new IDs and change your code appropriately.

Comment: Yup that was it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have *one* element with the same ID.  The `$("#id")` selector will only select the *first* element that has the `#append-tweets` ID, even if there is more than one (same applies to `document.getElementById`.

Either use a class (`.append-tweets`), or if you *must*, us the attribute selector (**not recommended**): `$("[id=append-tweets]")`.

Comment: Embarassingly, that has fixed it. I swear I tried changing it to class an hour ago! Thanks for your help.